# Does a compiler collapse classes which are identical in their structure?

Tags: c++, class, duplicates, token

I hope this isn't a duplicate of a question itself, but the search terms are so ambiguous, I can't think of anything better.

Say we have two classes:

```
class FloatRect
{
 float x,y,width,height;
};
```

and somewhere else

```
class FloatBox
{
 float top,left,bottom,right;
};
```

From a practical standpoint, they're the same, so does the compiler treat them both as some sort of typedef?

Or will it produce two separate units of code?

I'm curious because I'd like to go beyond typedefs and make a few variants of a type to improve readability.

I don't want needless duplication, though...

Comment: Compile some code using either of these classes, and there won't be anything remotely resembling a class or an object in the result...

Comment: @delnan: I think he meant internal to the compiler, not internal to the resulting code (where, of course, class types no longer exist).

Comment: My apologies, I worded it rather badly, but I did mainly want to know if the output code would have duplicates, but both cases have been covered now. Final code == memory offset, compiler == two different types. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely implementation specific.

For example I can use CLang / LLVM to illustrate both point of view at once:

- CLang is the C++ front-end, it uses two distinct types to resolve function calls etc... and treats them as completely different values
- LLVM is the optimizer backend, it doesn't care (yet) about names, but only structural representation, and will therefore collapse them in a single type... or even entirely remove the time definition if useless.

If the question is about: does introducing a similarly laid-out class creates overhead, then the answer is **no**, so write the classes that you need.

*Note: the same happens for functions, ie the optimizer can merge blocks of functions that are identical to get tighter code, this is not a reason to copy/paste though*

Answer (score 2):

They are totally unrelated classes with regards to the compiler.

If they are just POD C-structs, it won't actually generate any real code for them as such. (Yes there is a silent assignment operator and some other functions but I doubt there will be code actually compiled to do it, it will just inline them if they are used).

Comment: For every compiler ever? You can guarantee this?

Comment: @Tomalak: You can't guarantee *anything* about what happens to a program in the guts of the compiling process. The standard only describes what the input has to look like and how the program seems to ("as if") behave at runtime (plus some diagnostics the compiler must/should provide, if I remember correctly).

Comment: @delnan: Correct. :) My question was rhetorical, because in fact CashCow cannot guarantee that his answer is correct at all.

Answer (score 2):

Since the classes you use as samples are only relevant during compilation, there's nothing to duplicate or collapse. Runtime, the member variables are simply accessed as "the value at at offset N".

Comment: I think the OP meant internal to the compiler, not internal to the output code.

Answer (score 2):

This is, of course, hugely implementation-specific.

Any internal collapse here would be completely internal to the mechanism of the compiler, and would not have an effect on the produced translated code.

I would imagine it's very unlikely that this is the case, as I can think of no benefit and several ways in which this would really complicate matters. I can't present any evidence, though.

Answer (score 1):

No. As they are literally two different types.
The compiler must treat them that way.
There is no magic merging going on.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not treated as typedefs, because they are different types and can for example be used for overloading functions.

On the other hand, the types have no code in them so there will be nothing to duplicate.